# Regex: match everything the other regex left

Tags: java, regex

I am struggling with the following issue: say there's a regex 1 and there's regex 2 which should match everything the regex 1 does not.

Let's have the regex 1:
`/\$\d+/` (i.e. the dollar sign followed by any amount of digits.

Having a string like `foo$12___bar___$34wilma buzz` it detects `$12` and `$34`.

How does the regex 2 should look in order to match the remained parts of the aforementioned string, i.e. `foo`, `___bar___` and `wilma buzz`? In other words it should pick up all the "remained" chunks of the source string.

Comment: Not very efficient, but  perhaps a capturing group `\$\d+|((?:(?!\$\d+).)+)` https://regex101.com/r/Uad7ME/1

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You may use `String#split` to split on given regex and get remaining substrings in an array:

```
String[] arr = str.split( "\\$\\d+" );

//=> ["foo", "___bar___", "wilma buzz"]
```

[RegEx Demo](https://regex101.com/r/S9tqWb/1)

Comment: Thanks, but I specifically interested in the regex because I am dealing with some kind of "declarative" algorithm therefore I cannot use this approach.

Comment: This is very much regex approach itself.

Answer (score 0):

It was tricky to get this working, but this regex will match everything besides `\$\d+` for you. EDIT: no longer erroneously matches `$44$444` or similar.

```regex
(?!\$\d+)(.+?)\$\d+|\$\d+|(?!\$\d+)(.+)

Breakdown


(?!\$\d+)(.+?)\$\d+
(?!     )                   negative lookahead: assert the following string does not match
   \$\d+                    your pattern - can be replaced with another pattern
         (.+?)              match at least one symbol, as few as possible
              \$\d+         non-capturing match your pattern

OR

\$\d+                       non-capturing group: matches one instance of your pattern

OR

(?!\$\d+)(.+)
(?!\$\d+)                   negative lookahead to not match your pattern
         (.+)              match at least one symbol, as few as possible


GENERIC FORM
(?!<pattern>)(.+?)<pattern>|<pattern>|(?!<pattern>)(.+)
```

By replacing `<pattern>`, you can match anything that doesn't match your pattern. Here's one that [matches your pattern,](https://regex101.com/r/1CaLeJ/11/) and here's [an example of arbitrary pattern (un)matching.](https://regex101.com/r/1CaLeJ/12/)

Good luck!

Comment: Actually, it is a [wrong approach](https://regex101.com/r/gOY1wF/1). The digits get matched in the consecutive `\$\d+` patterns.

Comment: Good catch - I'll modify the regex.

Comment: You can't do any better in Java than what [Thefourthbird suggested](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/57615221/regex-match-everything-the-other-regex-left/57615989?noredirect=1#comment101685568_57615221). Actually, in Java, you can't write a regex that matches any text other than some multicharacter string. With capturing, something can be done, but it is inefficient, I would not recommend this.

Comment: I was playing around with it and arrived at The fourth bird's comment suggestion myself. Looks like there's no better way to do this.

Comment: @WiktorStribiżew I take it back, I got one that's *barely* more efficient than Thefourthbird's - posting it now.

Comment: Ok, so the capturing approach. Note you do not need all the non-capturing groups here, you may remove them. The pattern is very verbose though, and note that `.` does not match newline by default. Once the text between two matching patterns is very large, Java regex engine may halt, and you will need to unroll the lazy dot. So, as I say, it is nice from an educational point of view, but rather impractical and fragile.

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/198333/discussion-between-nick-reed-and-wiktor-stribizew).

Answer (score -2):

Try this one

```
[a-zA-Z_]+
```

Or even better

```
[^\$\d]+ -> With the ^symbol you can negotiate the search like ! in the java -> not equal
```

Comment: It will fail to match a digit anywhere but OP wants to disallow `$\d+` only

Comment: This is a wrong answer: `[^\$\d]+` matches any 1+ chars other than `$` and digit, not any text but `$` and a digit.

Comment: Fails many test cases: [here](https://regex101.com/r/1CaLeJ/8) and [here](https://regex101.com/r/1CaLeJ/7/).